# How to add controls in ToolTip

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tooltip

I have developed a control and uses it as a ToolTip for my purpose.

I am in need of adding a control in ToolTip. So i have added the control to be added in tooltip in OnLayout of my tooltip control. Control is adding fine. But the added control is not rendering at first time. Only rendering from second time showing only.

```
public ToolTipControl : Control
{
   NativeToolTip.TOOLINFO toolInfo;

   public ToolTipControl()
   {
      toolInfo = new NativeToolTip.TOOLINFO();
      toolInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(toolInfo);
      toolInfo.uFlags = WindowMessages.TTF_IDISHWND;
      toolInfo.hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
      toolInfo.uId = IntPtr.Zero;
      toolInfo.rect = new NativePaint.RECT();
      toolInfo.hinst = IntPtr.Zero;
      toolInfo.lpszText = (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto("tooltip");
      toolInfo.lParam = IntPtr.Zero;

   }

   public void SetToolTip(Control control)
   {
       if (control == null)
           return;

       control.HandleCreated += OnControlHandleCreated;

       if (control.IsHandleCreated)
           OnControlHandleCreated(control, EventArgs.Empty);
    }


    private void OnControlHandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Control control = sender as Control;

       if (control == null)
          return;

       toolInfo.hwnd = this.Handle;
       toolInfo.uId = control.Handle;

       NativeToolTip.SendMessage(this.Handle, WindowMessages.TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, ref toolInfo);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
       get
       {
          CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
          param.ClassName = "tooltips_class32";
          param.Style = unchecked(WindowMessages.WS_POPUP) | WindowMessages.TTS_ALWAYSTIP;
          param.ExStyle |= WindowMessages.WS_EX_TOPMOST;
          return param;
       }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
       base.WndProc(ref m);
       switch (m.Msg)
       {
          case (int)WindowMessages.WM_NOTIFY:
          {
             NativeToolTip.NMHDR hdr = (NativeToolTip.NMHDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(NativeToolTip.NMHDR));
             switch (hdr.code)
             {
                case (int)WindowMessages.TTN_SHOW:
                    OnPopup(GetControl(hdr.hwndFrom, (IntPtr)hdr.idFrom), ref m);
                    return;

             }
        }
    }    

    void OnPopup(Control control, ref Message m)
    {
       Info info = this.GetInfo(control);

       if (info == null)
           return;

       this.Info = info;
       this.PerformLayout();
    }

    public Info Info
    {
       get;
       set;
    }

    protected override OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.Info==null)
        {
            this.Size= Size.Empty;
            return;
        }

        Control control= this.Info.Control;
        this.Size= control.Size;           

        this.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

Does anyone please let me know, why the added controls are not rendered at first time?

Regards,

Comment: can you please provide some sample code that is giving you this issue

Comment: _I have developed a control and uses it as a ToolTip for my purpose._ Good for you. But we know nothing about your control, so we can't really help effectively.. Show us some minimal code..!

Comment: Please refer to the sample code in the edit.